# Got error while copying existing record in new one in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, copy

Hi i am creating an action to copy an existing record in a new one in rails3 which is correctly populates the values from previous record to new one but at the time i submit the form it gives the error. Here is my code sample

```
 class SalaryStructuresController < ApplicationController
     def new
        @salary_structure = SalaryStructure.new
        @salary_structure.salary_structure_line_items.build 
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @salary_structure }
        end
      end
     def create
        @salary_structure = SalaryStructure.new(params[:salary_structure])
        @salary_structure.company_id = current_company.id
        @salary_structure.created_by = current_user.id
        respond_to do |format|
          if @salary_structure.valid?
            @salary_structure.save_with_variable_payheads
            flash[:success]= "Salary structure successfully created."
            format.html { redirect_to(@salary_structure) }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @salary_structure, :status => :created, :location => @salary_structure }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @salary_structure.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

 #action to clone the salary structure
     def copy
       @payheads = current_company.payheads
        @users = current_company.users
        @source_salary_structure = SalaryStructure.find(params[:id])
        @salary_structure = SalaryStructure.new(@source_salary_structure.attributes)
        @source_salary_structure.salary_structure_line_items.each do |line_item|
         salary_item = SalaryStructureLineItem.new(line_item.attributes)
         @salary_structure.salary_structure_line_items << salary_item
       end 

       render :action => "new" 
     end
    end
```

My model:

```
class SalaryStructure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :salary_structure_line_items
  belongs_to :user
#  has_many :payheads


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :salary_structure_line_items, :reject_if => lambda {|p| p[:payhead_id].blank? && p[:amount].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  #validation
  validates_presence_of :effective_from_date, :for_employee
  validates_presence_of :salary_structure_line_items
  validates_associated :salary_structure_line_items

  attr_accessible :id, :effective_from_date, :salary_structure_line_items_attributes, :amount, :total, :pay_head_type, :for_employee, :pay_head, :created_by, :updated_at, :created_at, :company_id,
                      :salary_structure_line_items_attributes
end
```

When i submit the form (press save) i got the error on salary_structure_id:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SalaryStructuresController#create

Couldn't find SalaryStructureLineItem with ID=11 for SalaryStructure with ID=
```

Even in parameters salary_structure_id is present :

```
"commit"=>"Save",
 "salary_structure"=>{"salary_structure_line_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"amount"=>"3000.0",
 "_destroy"=>"",
 "salary_structure_id"=>"4",
 "id"=>"11",
 "payhead_id"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"amount"=>"500.0",
 "_destroy"=>"",
 "salary_structure_id"=>"4",
 "id"=>"12",
 "payhead_id"=>"2"}
```

i am unable to trace where i am missing something, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have created clone file in very easy way here i have created a new action in my controller

```
def copy_salary_structure
   @users = current_company.users.without_salary_structure
   @payheads = current_company.payheads.where(:optional => false)
   @old_salary_structure = SalaryStructure.find_by_id(params[:id])
   @salary_structure = SalaryStructure.new
   @salary_structure.company_id = @old_salary_structure.company_id
   @salary_structure.created_by = current_user.id

   @old_salary_structure.salary_structure_line_items.each do |line_item|
    salary_structure_line_item = SalaryStructureLineItem.new(
       :payhead_id => line_item.payhead_id,
       :amount => line_item.amount
      ) 
    @salary_structure.salary_structure_line_items << salary_structure_line_item
   end  
  end
```

and i have create a view form with same name from which i can review the record and then save it easily